# Is creating a large Vec full of sequential u64 faster via loop and push() or via collect()?

Tags: rust

I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this as I have to create a vector of about 600,000 `u64` integers.

Here is my first attempt:

```
fn latest_ids(current_id: u64, latest_id: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut ids: Vec<u64> = vec![];
    let mut start = current_id;
    while !(start >= latest_id) {
        start += 1;
        ids.push(start);
    }
    ids
}
```

Second attempt:

```
fn latest_ids(current_id: u64, latest_id: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let ids: Vec<u64> = (current_id+1..latest_id).collect();
    ids
}
```

The second version is much shorter/cleaner, but I am not sure how efficient `collect()` is going to be? Or perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: `!(start >= latest_id)` - Why so complicated? Why not `start < latest_id`?

Comment: Woops.. Good point. I missed that one.

Comment: Note: you can simplify the second version to just `(current_id+1..latest_id).collect()`. No need for the `let` binding. Just have the `collect()` expression be the last one in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ever in doubt about performance in Rust, don't forget about [benchmarks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.16.0/book/benchmark-tests.html).

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use test::Bencher;

    const CURRENT_ID: u64 = 1;
    const LATEST_ID: u64 = 60000;

    #[bench]
    fn push(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let mut ids: Vec<u64> = vec![];
            let mut start = CURRENT_ID;

            while !(start >= LATEST_ID) {
                start += 1;
                ids.push(start);
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn collect(b: &mut Bencher) {
        b.iter(|| {
            let _ids: Vec<u64> = (CURRENT_ID + 1..LATEST_ID).collect();
        });
    }
}
```

Running `cargo bench`,

```
running 2 tests
test tests::collect ... bench:      29,931 ns/iter (+/- 6,842)
test tests::push    ... bench:      85,701 ns/iter (+/- 18,096)
```

You can see that `collect` is actually faster than `push` (by a lot). I'm guessing this has to do with `push` sometimes having to clone the whole `Vec` and move it to a different location in memory (don't quote me on that though).

Comment: Your reasoning on the slowdown is correct. You can make the `push` version faster (though probably still not quite as fast as the `collect` version) by using `vec::with_capacity(LATEST_ID - CURRENT_ID)` instead of `vec![]`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl that makes sense, but why is `collect` so much faster though? What does it do different?

Comment: @EvilRobotOverlord It calls `size_hint` on the range iterator, and since that iterator knows exactly how many elements it has, this allows the vec to precisely allocate enough space and copy the elements without any range checks.

Comment: While the conclusion is correct (AFAICT), the benchmarks are incorrect. The created vectors are never used, so the compiler could just remove everything, leading to a phenomenal time of 0 ns (yes, it didn't in this case, but it's still dangerous). In benchmarks you always have to make sure that your result is used or dummy-used. There is `test::black_box` exactly for that purpose. Even better: you can return a value from the closure in `iter()` which is put into a black box. So just return `ids` from that closure to fix the benchmark.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Additionally, `collect` may use `memcpy`, depending on the `Iterator`.